# MySQL PROCEDURE ANALYZE suggesting CHAR instead of INT?

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.6

I've created an empty table with one field and imported some numeric data into it. The field named **value1** I chose as a TEXT field. (I did so temporarily as I did not know the length/range of the data or whether there may be a stray alpha character in the data and etc.)

Now, when cleaning things up PROCEDURE ANALYZE() tells me that **value1** should be a **CHAR(6)** field. The field is numeric, it has no alpha chars, it has a MIN value of 1 and MAX value of 9999, a MIN length of 1 and a MAX length of 6. So after a little more investigation, I saw there were zero-padded values i.e. 000123. In case that was the problem, I cleaned it up with some SQL:

```
UPDATE table1 SET value1=TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM value1)
```

So now everything looks good, regexp searches don't show up any alpha chars and so on. Yet PROCEDURE ANALYZE() now tells me that **value1** should be a CHAR(5) field. There are no empty fields. The charset was latin, and so I tried ALTER TABLE table1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8. No change.

Does anyone know what I may be missing or not understanding here? Why is it not telling me to use SMALLINT or such?

Mysql 5.6, InnoDB table, utf8.

Comment: "Why is it not telling me to use SMALLINT or such?" --- how would it know?

Comment: There does not appear to be any non-numeric values in the data, I would of thought SMALLINT would be the best choice?

Comment: it's not that smart. And none of the tools know your real model requirements to make the correct prediction

Comment: Perhaps you are right. I just created another table and inserted random integers.... analyze tells me CHAR is the best storage method.

Comment: it's not the "best". It's the one that could fit the data you're already storing. But it doesn't know your **real** requirements

Comment: hmm, I guess I am just surprised. I would of thought it would pick up on numeric only values. (and I assume smallint is efficient/faster than char... but could be wrong there too!) Cheers for your response!